# Using Linear Discriminant Analysis to perform feature extraction class labels of observations are changed

Tags: r, spam, document-classification

I'm looking at different methods to classify email in the UCI spambase dataset as spam or not spam.

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/spambase

As there are 58 variables (including the dependent) I thought to use Linear Discriminant Analysis(LDA) for dimension reduction and then the other classifiers such as SVM etc. to check for any improvement in classification accuracy.

However, while the accuracy did increase the class labels( what denotes each email as spam or not spam) of some of the observations change.

Before I run the LDA I have:
In the training_set
nonspam 1952
spam 1269
In the test_set
nonspam 836
spam 544

After I run the LDA I have:
In the training_set
nonspam 2131
spam 1090
In the test_set
nonspam 919
spam 461

this is before I before the actual classification(SVM). How do I stop this? Thx in advance.

```
#Linear Discriminant Analysis
setseed = 100
kfolds = 10

# Importing the dataset
dataset = read.csv('spambase.csv')

# Encoding the target feature as factor
dataset$factor = as.factor(dataset$factor)

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
library(caTools)
set.seed(setseed)
split = sample.split(dataset$factor, SplitRatio = 0.7)
training_set = subset(dataset, split == TRUE)
test_set = subset(dataset, split == FALSE)

# Feature Scaling
training_set[-58] = scale(training_set[-58])
test_set[-58] = scale(test_set[-58])

sum(training_set[,58]==0)
sum(training_set[,58]==1)

sum(test_set[,58]==0)
sum(test_set[,58]==1)

# Fitting classifier to the Training set
library(MASS)
library(e1071)
LDA =lda(formula = factor ~ ., data = training_set)

training_set = as.data.frame(predict(LDA, training_set))
training_set = training_set[c(4, 1)]
test_set = as.data.frame(predict(LDA, test_set))
test_set = test_set[c(4, 1)]

sum(training_set[,2]==0)
sum(training_set[,2]==1)

sum(test_set[,2]==0)
sum(test_set[,2]==1)

classifier = svm(formula = class ~ ., data = training_set,
                 type = 'C-classification', kernel = 'linear')

# Predicting the Test set results
pred = predict(classifier, newdata = test_set[-58])

# Making the Confusion Matrix
cm = table(test_set$class,pred)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Why would you expect to get the same result after you change the model?

Comment: The LDA, in this case, is for dimension reduction and not classification.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But if you run a classifier before the LDA, it's using all of the available dimensions. After the LDA, you are using a reduced set of dimensions. Why would you expect the classifications to be unchanged?

Comment: I’m confused. Can I use LDA to reduce the number of dimensions/ feature extraction? If I can and I do reduce the number of dimensions of the dataset shouldn’t the class labels of each observation (the dependent variable) be the same as before? (What was regular email is now spam and vice versa)( not talking about classification yet). If the class labels for each observation change before the classification how can I then interpret the model and it’s results when I actually do perform the classification? Also no actual classification was run just the LDA to reduce dimensions

Comment: Thx for responding btw